# Is it possible to delete an image loaded to "Change your picture" for user profile?

Tags: support, profile-picture

While considering if I wanted to change my user image to something less abstract I came across a question that I could not find the answer to.

It seems to me that there is no way to remove an uploaded image from the list of images to change a user profile to.

Am I just missing something or is there actually no way to remove these uploaded images?

Comment: Those images are loaded to imgur like any other image uploaded to posts, so the answer in the linked question is valid in your case as well: no, such thing is not possible.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Okay, thanks. If I remove them from imgur, will they no longer show up in the list of images which pops out in my profile?

Comment: What list? There are only two: your Gravatar image and last uploaded image.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yeah, I was a little wary about adding any in case they cannot be deleted (didn't realize they were hosted by imgur). I didn't want to have whichever image I uploaded as an option stay around forever.